# Show that $x^{n-1}y^{n-1} = (yx)^{n-1}$ in a group G where $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$ for some fixed n.

Tags: group-theory

I'm sure there is a simple trick but I'm not sure what to do.

Some attempts:

$x^{n-1}y^{n-1} = x^{-1}x^ny^ny^{-1} = x^{-1}(xy)^ny^{-1}$

$(yx)^{n-1} = (yx)^n(yx)^{-1} = y^nx^{n-1}y^{-1}$

$(yx)^{n-1} = (yx)^{-1}(yx)^n = x^{-1}y^{n-1}x^n$

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any hints?

Comment: The first attempt is a good start. Just expand $(xy)^n$. Try to do it for a small $n$ if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a simple trick!

If $(xy)^n = x^n y^n$ then $xy (xy)^{n-2} xy = x^n y^n$ and so, erasing $x$ left and $y$ right
$$y(xy)^{n-2}x = x^{n-1}y^{n-1}$$

Now just observe that $y(xy)^{n-2}x = (yx)^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\begin{align}
(xy)^n=x^ny^n&\implies x(yx)^{n-1}y=x(x^{n-1}y^{n-1})y\\
&\implies (yx)^{n-1}=x^{n-1}y^{n-1}.
\end{align}$$