# Is $(b^{-1}(ba)b)^n = b^{-1}(ba)^nb $ when $(ab)^n=a^n*b^n$ for any a,b in G under * and n>1 a fixed integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve this problem from an  abstract algebra book. It reads

Suppose $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for all a,b in G where n>1 is a fixed integer.

Show that, $(ab)^{n-1} = b^{n-1}a^{n-1}$

And then the proof starts with

We have, $(b^{-1}(ba)b)^n = b^{-1}(ba)^nb$

I couldn't make out why this should be true.
Shouldn't this instead be
$(b^{-1}(ba)b)^n = b^{-n}(ba)^nb^n$ ?

Comment: First step : We have $b^{-1}*(ba)*b=a*b$

Comment: That makes sense, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Write it out longhand for $n=2, 3$ and I think you'll have some insight as to why the book is correct.

Comment: I never have claimed that this is already the full solution. The right side is $abab\cdots ab$ with $n$ a's and $n$ b's. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Unless there is very good reason, it is best to omit the operation symbol and simply use juxtaposition when dealing with multiplicative notation.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, a and b have to be commutative for it to be true. But since n is fixed, G cannot be abelian(?).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $x^{n-1}y^{n-1} = (yx)^{n-1}$ in a group G where $(xy)^n = x^ny^n$ for some fixed n.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479502/show-that-xn-1yn-1-yxn-1-in-a-group-g-where-xyn-xnyn-for) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(ab)%5En%3Da%5Enb%5En%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24(ab)%5E%7Bn-1%7D%3Db%5E%7Bn-1%7Da%5E%7Bn-1%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: @JohnOmielan That post belongs to the same problem as mine, but doesn't give insight to the part of the proof that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** As Robert Shore mentioned, expanding gives you what you want,
\begin{align*}
(b^{-1}(ba)b)^n &= \underbrace{(b^{-1}(ba)b)(b^{-1}(ba)b)\dots(b^{-1}(ba)b)}_{n \text{ times}} \\
&=b^{-1}(ba)(bb^{-1})(ba)(bb^{-1})\dots(bb^{-1})(ba)b \\
&= b^{-1}\underbrace{(ba)(ba)\dots(ba)}_{n \text{ times}} b\\
& = b^{-1}(ba)^nb.
\end{align*}
Remember that the group operation is associative, so $(gh)k = g(hk)$.

Comment: I rather thaught that $(ab)^n = a^nb^n = b^na^n = (ba)^n$ for one specific value of n, in which case the statement becomes trivial to prove. Can you confirm whether my assumption is true?

Comment: It's for one specific value of $n$, but you don't get to commute $a^nb^n$.

Comment: I'm kinda confused at that point. Isn't commutivity necessary for $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for fixed n? Because expanding the left gives $ababab....$ n times. How do you get to thr right without commuting?

Comment: It is not, note the duplicate post associated to your question proves your claim without using commutativity. Groups for which $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ are called $n$-abelian groups, and for $n>2$ there they need not be abelian.